# COLAB: Return values from a python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I am running a python script in colab and would like to then use the outputs of the script in other cells however whenever I try to use them they seem to be undefined.
`

```
from google.colab import drive

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
root_path = 'gdrive/MyDrive/folder
```

```
! python /content/gdrive/MyDrive/folder/main.py
```

For example if in the script I have something like:
`

```
def f(i):
    g=i
    return g


if __name__ == "__main__":
    G=[]
    for i in range(0,10):
        g = f(i)
        G.append(g)
    G=pd.DataFrame(G)
```

If I try to print G in colab after running the script then I get that it is undefined.

I tried saving these as csv files this did not work

`G.to_csv('filename.csv')`

Comment: Welcome to SO! `g` is undefined in the `__main__` block, so the `G.append(g)` should raise an error. The intention was probably something like: `G.append(h)`. Read through [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Apologies, I made a typo when making this minimal example of a function.

Comment: This question is pretty old and presumably moot, but `G` is only defined while the script is running. If you call `! python /content/gdrive/MyDrive/folder/main.py` from a cell, that will not define `G` in your current workbook, only in the script `main.py` itself while it's running.

Comment: If you want to call a function from another script and have its return value available in your workbook, you need to import that script and call its function, rather than run it via a system call.